# Vertical tabs / navigation in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

Short question: <s>Is it possible</s> How to have a navigation bar on vertical level?
For example, change [this Shiny's example app](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/navbar-example.html) in a way that navbar is vertical, on the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `shiny` has vertical navbar. You'll probably have to hack it or you could potentially simulate it using a combination of `sidebarLayout` and `conditionalPanel`.

An alternative and easiest way though is to use the `shinydashboard` package. See image below.

[image]

Comment: That's something that might work. If you have expertise, what are the main differences between `shiny` / `shinydashboard`?

Comment: They are very similar. If you already know `shiny` then you shouldn't have any issues picking this up.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the suggestion. Last question: do you know if some visualization libraries (DT, plotly, ggplot2) behave differently in shinydashboard?

Comment: Developing a `shinydashboard` app is almost the same as a developing a regular `shiny` app. Just dive in and you'll pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

Shiny has `navlistPanel()`, which you can read more about on the [Shiny Application Layout Guide](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html).

> [image: Shiny Navlists]
>
> ```
> ui <- fluidPage(
>
>   titlePanel("Application Title"),
>
>   navlistPanel(
>     "Header A",
>     tabPanel("Component 1"),
>     tabPanel("Component 2"),
>     "Header B",
>     tabPanel("Component 3"),
>     tabPanel("Component 4"),
>     "-----",
>     tabPanel("Component 5")
>   )
> )
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean like in a [Sidebar Layout?](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/sidebarLayout.html)

Comment: Imagine having a layout like the one you posted, but it has different outputs depending on a **vertical tabPanel()**. Check [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp) for visual representation of a vertical tabs I have in mind.

Comment: shinydashboard will have that in a framework for you, as answered below.